# ControlSend to inactive window - doesn't work

Tags: autohotkey

Before asking that question I made quick research about the problem and I really think that it should work. Can someone point out what's wrong with that code? I want to send specific text to the inactive Notepad window but I didn't get any response at all.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinNotexist, Untitled - Notepad
Run, Notepad.exe, , min
WinWait, Untitled - Notepad
ControlSend, Edit1, test1, Untitled - Notepad
sleep, 1000
ControlSend, Edit1, test2, Untitled - Notepad
Sleep, 1000 
return
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code is fine and works for me, don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Which OS version are you using? I still use Win7, but I read that Win10 often presents problems when AHK is not running with Admin rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided has been tested on Windows 7 with success.

```
F3::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinNotexist, Untitled - Notepad
Run, Notepad.exe, , min
WinWait, Untitled - Notepad
ControlSend, Edit1, test1, Untitled - Notepad
sleep, 1000
ControlSend, Edit1, test2, Untitled - Notepad
Sleep, 1000 
return
```

**Output in Notepad:**

```
test1test2
```

As @RobertIlbrink mentions, there are some behavioral issues that come up depending on the OS in question. Please verify that AutoHotkey is running the most up to date version, and follow up with more details so we can troubleshoot further.

**Edit per the comments:**

I'm wondering now if the Polish alphabet is causing the script to fail due to the WinTitle not being matched.

Perhaps try the following:

```
F3::
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx
Match = .*Notatnik
IfWinNotexist, %Match%
Run, Notepad.exe, , min
WinWait, %Match%
ControlSend, Edit1, test1, %Match%
sleep, 1000
ControlSend, Edit1, test2, %Match%
Sleep, 1000 
return
```

Comment: I'm running this script on Windows 7 with up-to-date version of AHK and with Admin rights - I've checked it twice. Interestingly other commands seem to work fine. I'm using "Send" command in other project and I have no problems.

Comment: @MateuszKnap Perhaps consider using the Window Spy to see what Notepad actually shows up as in your system.

Comment: I've got Polish version of Windows, so WinTitle is "Bez tytułu - Notatnik". That's the only difference. Nevertheless, even when I'm changing code regarding that fact - still nothing happens.

Comment: It works perfectly! I think it's a good hint for people with similar problem - diacritical marks cause problems with matching the WinTitle. Thank you!

Comment: @MateuszKnap I'm glad it worked; That was a tricky one. If that solves the issue in its entirety, please accept the answer so it's taken out of the Unanswered questions queue. :)